# Parameter Naming conventions for function in python

Tags: python, function, parameters, naming-conventions

This isn't a big deal of a question but it bothers me, so I decided to ask for inspiration.

Assume a function defined like this:

```
def store(book=None, author=None):
    pass
```

When calling this function like this:

```
book = Book()
author = Author()
store(book=book, author=author)
```

do I have to fear sideeffects because of `book=book` and `author=author`? I am tending to redefine the function to

```
def store(thebook=None, theauthor=None):
    pass
```

but it seems a little verbose. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no side effects to fear. It's no different semantically than it would be if you had just called

```
store(book, author)
```

The values are stored in new variables inside the function's scope, subject to all the normal python scoping rules.

Keyword arguments do free you to use other, more specific variable names if you need to though. The names `book` and `author` are pretty generic, which is appropriate within a function, which should be reusable and therefore a little bit more abstract. But using more specific names might be appropriate within the calling scope. From that perspective, `thebook` and `theauthor` aren't really any different from `book` and `author`; you'd want to do something more like -- say -- `local_book` or `borrowed_book` -- or whatever would more precisely describe the book in question.

Answer (score 3):

First, there's no ambiguity or side-effect in saying `store(book=book, author=author)`. The interpreter has no problem telling argument names from names in general.

Now, concerning the second part of your question, I don't think you should change the names of the function's arguments: after all, `store()` *does* perform its work from a `book` and an `author`, in the general sense.

Your local variables, however, might be more precise about what they contain. They probably don't reference *any* book or author, but one having specific characteristics like, say, the *current* book or the *best-selling* author.

So, if you wish to disambiguate names, I would suggest you rename your local variables instead.

Answer (score 2):

**No**, there won't be any side effects from that.

The namespace of the variables in the *calling* function, and the namespace of the parameters within the *called* function, are separate and can't affect each other.

Answer (score 1):

You will not get any problem with your parameter names being the same as your variable parameters because they are not parsed the same way:

```
parameters: '(' [varargslist] ')'
varargslist: ((fpdef ['=' test] ',')*
          ('*' NAME [',' '**' NAME] | '**' NAME) |
          fpdef ['=' test] (',' fpdef ['=' test])* [','])
```

From http://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html